# CSS selector length causing bugs, what's the cause?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

I have a lot of sass for a larger project spread over different files. The compiler then assembles all selectors with the same css and combines them in one css-selector. Seems good and efficient. However, in certain scenarios my css wouldn't work and it seemed to be due to selector size.

I found the following: when I use the 'New Style Rule'-button in Chrome DevTools I can add the following selector, hit tab and insert my css:

```
a.valign-wrapper:hover i.material-icons,
a.progress-bar:hover i.material-icons,
a.status:hover i.material-icons
```

However, this second selector doesn't work. When hitting tab it just disappears (without any feedback), seemingly meaning I can't use it.

```
a.valign-wrapper:hover i.material-icons,
a.progress-bar:hover i.material-icons,
a.status:hover i.material-icons,
.select-wrapper.box a.caret:hover::before i.material-icons
```

What is the cause of this? And also, would you know of a way to fix this? Since I'm using sass I can't just split the selector onto two lines, since sass will combine them when compiling.

**Update:**

To clarify the problem and show that it's something with chrome and/or css, here are some steps to reproduce (in Chrome):

1. Select the first selector from above -> Ctrl+C
2. Hit RMB -> Inspect on any page (this stackoverflow-page for example)
3. Click on the small plus-icon in the top-right corner of DevTools
4. Ctrl+V, thus pasting in the selector
5. Hit tab: you can now add css properties.
6. Reproduce the above steps, except copy the second selector from above instead of the first.
7. This time when you hit tab, you couldn't start adding css properties but instead the selector (and thus style rule) just disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't disappear, but it's not a selector for an *element*, per se, it's a selector for an element's *state*, the `:hover` state. That's why when you put in the dev tools it looks like it's gone, but it's not; it is there you just need to activate the `:hover` state using dev tools, on the element you want to see the rules.

To do that  `right-click` on the element whose state you want to change and select `:hover`

[image: SS]

OP's comment:

> If this were the cause, then both selectors would have the same
>   result, since both containing only :hover related selectors. Hitting
>   tab should let the user enter css that should be applicable to the
>   entered selector. However, the described behaviour is present.

That's because your last selector is a pseudo element `::before` so you need to select it after selecting the `:hover` state.

Something like this (notice yellow bullet - meaning `hover` state selected):

[image: SS]

If that doesn't work, it might be that your CSS selector doesn't match your DOM.

Comment: If this were the cause, then both selectors would have the same result, since both containing only :hover related selectors. Hitting tab should let the user enter css that should be applicable to the entered selector. However, the described behaviour is present.

Comment: This again doesn't solve the problem. Hitting tab in DevTools doesn't have anything to do with what element the selector corresponds to. If you open it up, select a random element, click the 'New Style Rule'-button and add a rule for a random selector (thus not corresponding with whatever element is selected) and you press tab; you can add in your css just fine. However, when you try the long selector from my post, hitting tab will make the entire Style Rule dissapear. Just try it out to see what I mean.

Comment: I added steps in the original post to reproduce the problem and show that it doesn't have to do with my markup.

Comment: Tested and retested, it has to do it pseudo-element `::before` as I explained in my answer. Try just put only the latter selector with the `::before` (not going to show up) then copy paste the selector WITHOUT the `::before` then it will show up. Nothing to do with the length of the selector